# Post form values using jquery and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a simple form to an email using PHP , but cannot get the actual ajax function to work.

This is the form:

```
<form id="quick-booking-form" method="post" action="#">
                    <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message">
                    </textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send the Message" id="SendTheForm">
                </form>
```

This is then sent to a separate Javascript function, which holds the ajax:

```
$(function() {  
            //alert("page loaded");
            $('#quick-booking-form').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("Start of function");
                var mail = $("#mail").val();
                var message = $("#message").val();
                alert("Mail: " + mail + " Message: " + message);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"process.php",
                    data:{ 
                        "mail": mail,
                        "message": message, 
                        },
                    dataType: "text"
                }).success(function(result){
                    alert(result);
                    //next line: end of function
                    }) ;

                //next line: end of ajax
            });
        //next line: end of script
        });
```

which should send the data to this PHP file (process.php):

```
$msg = $_POST['message'];
                $UserName = $_POST['mail'];

                $contact = "Booking Manager";
                $reply = "web-bookings@thesite.net";

                //Subject is always...
                $subject = "A message from ".$UserName;
                $from = $reply;

                //test data
                //$contactDetails = "test@test.net";


                // send message
                $message = "Message reads: ".$msg;
                //$to = "notify@test.com";
                $to = $_POST['mail'];
                //$headers = "From: " . $contact."\r\n"."Reply-To:".$reply;
                $headers = "From: " . $contact;
                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                echo "Mail Sent.";
```

What should happen is that the form is submitted. It then gets validated (code omitted) in validate.js . If it passes, the form data is sent to process.php. This in turn sends a notification message to notify@test.com .

What currently happens is that the `alert("Start of Function")` fires, and so does the alert showing the correct values.

And this is as far as it gets. The mail function does not seem to fire, and the last alert does not show either.

Comment: Help us help you. What isn't working? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Are there any errors in your javascript console? Does the XHR request on the network tab of your browser tools look correct?

Comment: Are you currently getting any of the alerts?

Comment: It's possible the default submit event is firing. Add `event.preventDefault()` to the beginning of your handler.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have a closing `</form>` tag and the first line of your PHP should be changed from `$msg = $_POST['mesage'];` to `$msg = $_POST['message'];` .  Still not sure if that's the problem or not.

Comment: dataType (which is default string I know, but does the PHP output even a string), success callback? Chaining `.done()` although expressed as a alternative method to the success callback is still going to fire regardless cause the AJAX is going to complete and trigger it. and I also agree with Fred-ii- to many errors, this looks like a hack job of code copied and pasted from various sources strung together and a few variables changed. Without regards to how things are actually working/meant to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are right but some changes, try this

```
$(function() {  
//alert("page loaded");
$('#quick-booking-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Start of function");
    var mail = $("#mail").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    alert("Mail: " + mail + "Message: " + message);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"process.php",
        data:{ 
            "mail": mail,
            "message": message, 
            },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(html) {
           alert(html);
        }
    });
    return false;

    //next line: end of ajax
    });
    //next line: end of script
  });
```

Use preventDefault function and success for ajax instead of done

Answer (score 0):

try this
Include JQUERY Library

HTML :

```
<form id="quick-booking-form" method="post" action="javascript:return false">
email:
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail">
<br/>
message: <textarea name="message" id="message">
</textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Send the Message" id="SendTheForm">
</from>
```

SCRIPT :

```
$(function() {  
    //alert("page loaded");
    $('#quick-booking-form').submit(function(event) {

        var mail = $("#mail").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        if(mail==""){
            alert("enter Mail"); return false;
         }
        if(message==""){
            alert("enter message"); return false;
         }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"process.php",
            data:{ 
                "mail": mail,
                "message": message, 
                },success:function(result){
                    alert(result);
                 }

        });

    //next line: end of ajax
    });
//next line: end of script
});
```

process.php :

```
$to =$_POST['mail'];
$subject = "Test mail";
$message =$_POST['mesage'];
$from = "bookings@test.net";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```